# Android Sensor data over USB

Tags: android, usb, accelerometer, transfer

I'm building a small app on my mac and wondering if there was some way to access the accelerometer data of a phone that is connected via USB. Will I have to develop an Android app that pushes this data to be received somehow? Or is there a way to access the data directly.

Thanks heaps for any help.

Comment: You can buy accelerometers for much less money than a phone.

Comment: Yes I'm sure thanks, thing is I already have the phone so I was hoping I could just use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at writing an Android app that polls for accelerometer data and send it via network. That will be a lot less painful than trying to send it via USB to a PC.

I doubt that your app will be sensitive to any latency and delays during intial development.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've decided to send the data over bluetooth. My main concern was latency but as you say with such small data it's not a huge issue it looks like.